# VB.NET 2012 : Select rows from DataView querying with 'Date'

Tags: vb.net

I have a table which contains a date column called `PurchaseDate`

I have a list box which displays the months. When I click a month , I need to query the dataSource and collect the rows which have the purchase date in the `SelectedMonth`.

```
dv2 = New DataView(ds.Tables(0), "PurchaseDate LIKE '" & SelectedMonth & "/%'", "BillNo", DataViewRowState.CurrentRows)
```

This code is not working. Because here `PurchaseDate` is in Date format like 'MM/DD/YYYY'. I think I need to convert the date into string before using `LIKE` operator. I also tried using as below. Even then, it didn't go fine.

```
dv1 = New DataView(ds.Tables(0), "convert(varchar2(20),PurchaseDate,103) LIKE '" & SelectedMonth & "/%'", "BillNo", DataViewRowState.CurrentRows)
```

Here `SelectedMonth` will be a string like '01', '10'..

Answer (score 1):

Use Linq to avoid such issues:

```
Dim selectedMonth = Int32.Parse(lbMonth.Text)
Dim filteredRows = From r In ds.Tables(0)
                   Where r.Field(Of Date)("PurchaseDate").Month = selectedMonth
' if you need a new DataTable
Dim tblFiltered = filteredRows.CopyToDataTable()
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what database you are using, so these are the culture independent date literals that I use in the same scenario...

Oracle

```
TO_DATE('18-Dec-2012','dd-Mon-yyyy')
```

SQL/Server

```
'18-Dec-2012'
```

Ms/Access (not culture independent, but it's the only thing MS/Access accepts)

```
#12/18/2012#
```

So you might format your SQL to say something like this...

```
PurchaseDate BETWEEN  '1-Dec-2012' AND '31-Dec-2012'
```